# How can I change how often iCloud data gets synced on my iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, icloud, macbook-pro

When I make changes to Contacts on my Macbook, they tend to take a while to get synced up with my iPhone 6. I was wondering if there was a setting on the iPhone (or perhaps even on iCloud.com) that would allow me to set a more frequent synch schedule.

Comment: if you close and reopen contacts app that should do the sysc now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible. Your iPhone automatically syncs your data with icloud.

Comment: You might want to rethink your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not timer setting for sync. Usually it is triggered by changes in a app like contacts.

If you want a instant sync Quit Contacts and restart. That should trigger the sync.